# Http Requset inside Loop For

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of products, some products have not imagens, hence i don't want show it, my imagens and products are get from webservices diferents.

I guess I'm not doing it the better way, becase aren't work!!

My code:

```
   List<ProductListObj> obj2 = obj;
    obj2.forEach((element) async{
      String url = _url.ImgProduto(codInterno: element.codProduto.toString());

      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

      if (response.statusCode == 404) {
        obj.removeWhere((element) => element.codProduto == element.codProduto);
      }
    });
   
    return obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a product list without images and you want to grab the images from the backend or so:
case 1: if you can access products images with a URL you can use cached_image_network it's a dependency that will help you load the image cache automatically.
case 2: you could get the image URL with the data and have a photoURL in your object class Then do the number 1 case.
Otherwise, explain more.

Comment: I'm using cahed_image_network, when haven't image i show "Image not found", however, how has many products without image, the main screen is be poor, so while my team don't get more imagens i'm tring hide this products the home, and if user search for it, I'll show the normal card, with details, but withou image.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the async are going to run separately. You should use `map` which will return List. Something like this would work

```
    List<ProductListObj> obj2 = obj;
    await Future.wait[obj2.map((element) async{
      String url = _url.ImgProduto(codInterno: element.codProduto.toString());

      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

      if (response.statusCode == 404) {
        obj.removeWhere((e) => e.codProduto == element.codProduto);
      }
    })];
   
    return obj;
```